# How does Subsonic handle concurrency?

Tags: concurrency, subsonic

Can somebody shed some light for me on how SubSonic 3.x handle concurrency? I checked out the document online but it's rather sparse at the moment. Any pointers and/or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't...

Comment: Thanks Rob, are there any plans to support this in a future release?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for this here that I am currently testing.

http://sites.google.com/site/subsonicoptimistic/home